# Comparing keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I generated a dictionary after reading a file. So now I want to evaluate the keys of the ditionary seperately, compare them in terms of . What I'm comparing are the ascii characters and only take those that may be less than 60. eg

```
for text in line:
 char = ord(text)
 num += 1

 if char in result:
    result[char].add(num)

 else:
    result[char] = set()
    result[char].add(num)

 row = list(result.keys())
```

This is what get me.

I tried

```
    for i in row:
        if row[I] < 60:
          print(result)
```

But it says "index out of range". Please help

Comment: What is `row[I]`? You don't have to iterate like this as `i` is already an element of `row`.

Comment: The loop variable `i` is a value from the list of keys (a number), so you probably want `if i < 60` rather than indexing `row` again.

Comment: What if I want a specific index from the row?

Comment: Um, that doesn't make sense. You're *looping* over the row, so `i` is going to have every value from it at one point or another. There's no specific index to get, since `i` isn't an index (it's a value). If you also need the index, use `enumerate` (`for index, value in enumerate(row)` or similar). But since your dictionary keys may be in a somewhat arbitrary order, the indexes are probably not very useful.

Comment: Understood. Is there a way to evaluate the keys of a dictionary without explicitly "removing" from the dictionary? In order to evaluate and print out print out only the ones less than 60?

Comment: You can loop directly over the dictionary itself (you'll get the keys with `for key in some_dict`). I don't really understand what you mean by '"removing" from the dictionary' though. It might help you to read [the documentation for Python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: By removing, I just meant by taking the keys and creating a list from them, like I had done.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are iterating over a list of dictionary keys, and then you are trying to index that list *with elements of the same list*. A list indexer must be an integer.

In essence, this is what your code is attempting:

```
lst = [10, 20, 30]

# this will fail on the first element, lst[10] does not exist
for i in [10, 20, 30]:
    if lst[i]:
```

What you can do instead is iterate over a range defined by the length of the list:

```
line = 'this is a test'

num = 0
result = {}
for text in line:
    char = ord(text)
    num += 1

    if char in result:
        result[char].add(num)

    else:
        result[char] = set()
        result[char].add(num)

row = list(result.keys())

print(result)

# {32: {5, 8, 10},
#  97: {9},
#  101: {12},
#  104: {2},
#  105: {3, 6},
#  115: {4, 7, 13},
#  116: {1, 11, 14}}

for i in range(len(row)):
    if row[i] < 60:
        print(row[i], result[row[i]])

# 32 {8, 10, 5}
```

---

You can implement this logic more efficiently using a dictionary comprehension. There is very rarely a need to make an explicit list out of your dictionary keys.

```
res = {k: v for k, v in result.items() if k < 60}
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable "i" should be lower case, like so:

```
if row[i] < 60
```

Comment: That was just autocorrect as I was typing. It is lowercase